# How to update PGP public key after new uid is added?

Tags: gnupg, pgp, public-key

I have a PGP keypair to which I just added a new uid.  Is the previously exported public key and private key still valid?  If I export a new public key with armor, it does look different and longer than the previously exported one.   Another related question is, when exporting public key, is it possible to only select specific uids to be recognized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public key is getting longer, as it's including your new uid. So your described behavior is what should happen.

As the exported key is not plain text, it's will change by changing some part of it. The same thing will happen, if you are getting signitures on it and exporting again. The exported key can now be imported by every of your communication partners or you can upload to a key server.

Exporting only some of your UID is not possible as far as I know.

Comment: Exported key files is plaintext as long as there is `--armor`.  So is the previously exported public and private keys (with armor enabled) still valid?  Do I need to update them on my web pages and email clients etc.?

Comment: They are still valid, but lagging your new UID. (I hope you don't have your private key on your homepage... it's only for your privat keyring). With plain text I meant human unreadable ;)

Comment: OK, i'll update the public key on my web site then so it can get the added uid.  Plain text normally just mean it is a file normally encoded as sequences of text characters.